# Adjacent sibling: too many elements between the rules

Tags: html, css, hover, hide, siblings

Im trying to get an p element unhide when the first top element of the visible tree is at hover. I checked here via stackoverflow that with adjacent sibling selectors it works great, and I runned a little example, but when I have too many elements between those two you want to sync it doesnt work.

```
#smart:hover ~ p#first {
display: inline;
}

#first {
left: -450px;
top: 100px;
display:none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/sietedosfede/pen/gdLiB

Trouble is if I try to put those two elements one next to each other, the css of tree will broke.

I ask if maybe exist a rule of that can just ignore middle elements between those two.

Anyway, I dont know if this is best way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance, GRiS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't to "up" the tree with css. You are trying to hover a nested element to display something that is not  part of the `<ul>` tree, and it won't work. You will have to use javascript instead or add the paragraph to the same list item where the anchor tag sit (or as a child element of the list item).